# New Wordpress Multisite Site NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: wordpress, ssl, subdomain, multisite

I am wanting to consolidate all my WP installs on my server into one install with WP Multisite. I have to use subdomains instead of subdirectories since it was an existing site, so I created my first multisite site called, 'kingdomchoirs.creativelight.co' When I try to go to the dashboard login of 'kingdomchoirs.creativelight.co/wp-admin' I get this error:

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I am a networking novice and the only helpful info I can come up with is this:

Besides the WP install in my root public_html directory on my server, all other WP installs are at subdomains that are named the same as what I need to name them for Multisite. For instance my Multisite path is 'kingdomchoirs.creativelight.co' and my existing site on my server is already 'kingdomchoirs.creativelight.co'

Is this the discrepancy? If so and if not, how do I resolve this?

Possible relevant code from wp_config:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'creativelight.co');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know what to do from here. I contacted my hosting and they said it was the WP Multisite setup. They had me open a private window and the subdomains load in the private window, then they had me clear the cookies and cache and it still doesn't work. I'm at the brink of my aptitude with this.

Comment: Never-mind. I contacted my host again and they misconfigured my Wildcard SSL. Thanks again.